# Why does camera app work fine without the needed permissions?

Tags: android

I have `FileProvider`:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/files"/>

        </provider>
```

files.xml:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="crime-photos" path="."/>
</paths>
```

also i have the following listener:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider",
                    mPhotoFile);
                captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);

                List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities =
                    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureImage,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

                for(ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities){
                    getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
                        uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                }

                startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO);

            }
```

It works fine. I press the button, then i can take a photo and then i get back to the activity. But then i tried to comment some lines:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider",
                    mPhotoFile);
                captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);

//              List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities =
//                  packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureImage,
//                      PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
//
//              for(ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities){
//                  getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
//                      uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
//              }

                startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO);

            }
```

I expected that my app will crash after taking a photo because the activity that do this doesn't have the `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` permission. But it still works fine as if i didn't comment that lines. **Why ?**

Comment: We can only tell you that when we know the value of mPhotoFile.

Comment: File mPhotoFile = new File(getContext.getFilesDir(), "name_of_photo_.jpg");@blackapps

Comment: @blackapps i've also added value of files.xml in my question

Comment: That is a private storage location for which your app does not any permission to write to and read from.

Comment: @blackapps So my app can't write to and read from its own `files` file but other apps can do this without any permissions ?

Comment: ??? Your question is very strange. Your app can write and read to its app specific directory (getFilesDir()) as much as it wants without any permission. That was said. Nothing more. Your conclusion is wrong and not logical at all.

Comment: @blackapps ok, sorry for this. So in my case the activity from other app that takes a photo is also a part of my app and that's why it doesn't need the permission ?

Comment: Activities from other apps are NOT part of your app.

Comment: `Why does my app work fine without the needed permissions?` My god.. wrong confusing subject. You mean: Why can the camara app write to my fileprovider uri without FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION?

Comment: Well i dont know. Which Android version on used device?

Comment: @blackapps `You mean: why can the camara app write to my fileprovider uri without FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION?` yes! i mean exactly this :) i tried on 24, 30 and 32 api. The result is the same.